# ActiveRecord without Rails Please install the mysql2 adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to access a mysql database using ruby with ActiveRecord. The ruby file is dbtest.rb.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'  
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
  :adapter => "mysql2",  
  :host => "localhost",  
  :database => "students"  
)  

class Rubyist < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

When I try to load this file via irb or run it using ruby I get the following error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in  `require': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`
```

I've installed both the mysql2 gem and activerecord-mysql2-adapter successfully.  When I installed the activerecord-mysql2-adapter I received the following messages:

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
Fetching: activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3
1 gem installed
```

Do I need to rename the adapter?

Comment: Pls run 'bundle update'.

Comment: I'm not using Rails, therefore I don't have a Gemfile and doesn't Bundle require a Gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

I added "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" to my .bash_profile which fixed it.